# assemble.io - context of yaml data in partials not working

Tags: yaml, assemble

I have an issue with YAML rendering content within partials using Assemble

Here is my breakdown:

**layout/deafualt.hbs**

```
<body>
        {{pagetitle}} <!-- THIS WILL RENDER 'HELLO WORLD' FINE -->
        <header role="banner">
            {{> _header }}
        </header>
        <main role="main">
            {{> body }}
        </main>
        <footer role="contentinfo">
            {{> _footer }}
        </footer>
    </body>
```

**pages/car.hbs**

```
---
pagetitle: "HELLO WORLD"
---
{{#car }}
    {{> banner }}
    {{> content }}
    {{> explore }}
    {{> feature }}
    {{> social }}
{{/car }}
```

**modules/content.hbs**

```
<h1>{{pagetitle}}</h1> <!-- THIS ***WON'T*** RENDER 'HELLO WORLD'-->
<h>Im a sub-heading</h2>
```

I imagine that its something to do with the context but I've tried various permutations to no avail.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

A.

Answer (score 1):

This is a handlebars issue more than Assemble. With handlebars it gets tricky when you use partials in nested blocks.

Given your example, in `content.hbs` try doing `{{car.pagetitle}}` since you're inside the `{{#car}}...{{/car}}` block.